# How to Translate Codeigniter Pre Formatted Query Into an Original Mysql Query (e.g $this->db->select('table1.*,table2.*,table3.*'))

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a website which is using a CodeIgniter framework and almost using CodeIgniter's preformatted query class in every request to process data from database built by my ex coworker.

One of the example is like this:

```
function tampilkan_data(){
      $this->db->select('barang.*,barang_keluar.*,barang_masuk.*');
      $this->db->from('barang');
      $this->db->join('barang_keluar', 'barang.id_barang=barang_keluar.id_barang','left');
      $this->db->join('barang_masuk', 'barang.id_barang=barang_masuk.id_barang','left');
      $this->db->order_by('barang.id_barang','asc');
      $this->db->order_by('barang.kode_barang','asc');
      $this->db->where('barang.status','0');
      return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```

I want to change the result from that query, but in order to understand it first I have to translate it into an original MySQL query. Attempted to do this:

```
SELECT `barang`.*, `barang_keluar`.*, `barang_masuk`.*
FROM `barang` AS A
LEFT JOIN `barang_keluar` AS B ON A.id_barang = B.id_barang
LEFT JOIN `barang_masuk` AS C ON A.id_barang = C.id_barang
ORDER BY A.id_barang ASC, A.kode_barang ASC
WHERE A.status = 0
```

But I got this error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE A.status = 0 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

I tried to remove the `WHERE A.status = 0` to see which is wrong from my code the I got this error

> ## 1051 - Unknown table 'barang'

I thought the problem is in the line `SELECT barang.*, barang_keluar.*, barang_masuk.*`, because I didn't really know how to write it in an MySQL original formatted.

I already searched for this topic and I even tried to write the query straight to the search bar but I didn't find the right approach according to my case.
Hope someone can help

Comment: Have you used pagination with this query?

Comment: Pagination? Maybe you want to give me enhancement to page the result that I get, but my point is how to write the pure MySQL script translated from CodeIgniter's builder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can simply print your query, Then you can see your query in original sql format.**

```
function tampilkan_data(){
    $this->db->select('barang.*,barang_keluar.*,barang_masuk.*');
    $this->db->from('barang');
    $this->db->join('barang_keluar', 'barang.id_barang=barang_keluar.id_barang','left');
    $this->db->join('barang_masuk', 'barang.id_barang=barang_masuk.id_barang','left');
    $this->db->order_by('barang.id_barang','asc');
    $this->db->order_by('barang.kode_barang','asc');
    $this->db->where('barang.status','0');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result(); // notice that i have removed the return keyword
    echo $this->db->last_query(); // This will print your query directly on the screen.
}
```

But the error which you are getting is -> You don't  have a table named barang.
Make sure that the table exists.

Hope It Helps...

Comment: Well thanks, this is what I get `SELECT barang.*, barang_keluar.*, barang_masuk.* FROM (barang) LEFT JOIN barang_keluar ON barang.id_barang=barang_keluar.id_barang LEFT JOIN barang_masuk ON barang.id_barang=barang_masuk.id_barang WHERE barang.status = 0 ORDER BY barang.id_barang asc, barang.kode_barang asc`. I think it not too much different, except the brackets..

Comment: Ok now I got it. You need replace -> SELECT `barang`.*, `barang_keluar`.*, `barang_masuk`.* to SELECT `A`.*, `B`.*, `C`.*, because you are using aliases

Comment: I think simply doing `SELECT * FROM...` will pull all fields from all joined tables.

Comment: @DFriend Well that's my problem mate, I only want to pull a few column not using `Table.*`..

Comment: @Riosant Well that `echo $this->db->last_query();` saved me, ease me to modify the query.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at the query string generated by the CI Query builder then you can log this method `$this->db->last_query()` which will give the last SQL query as string executed by it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is almost ok. But you will have to change it on **order by**. Because u have used **asc** more than once, that is not supported by mysql as well. You need to modify your query like below

```
    SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM barang AS A
LEFT JOIN barang_keluar AS B ON A.id_barang = B.id_barang
LEFT JOIN barang_masuk AS C ON A.id_barang = C.id_barang 
WHERE A.status = 0 ORDER BY A.id_barang, A.kode_barang ASC
```

Now be confirm that you have table **barang** in your database and try again. If you face another sql problem just reply with your screenshot of code snippet here.

Comment: Look tried here but oddly `barang` table isn't found. Check it out https://ibb.co/WVzKx18

Comment: You need replace -> SELECT barang.*, barang_keluar.*, barang_masuk.* to SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*, because you are using aliases

Comment: Ya that can be the issue. Check again my comment . I have edited it.