# How to convert sql query using between to codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have sql query that i need to convert to codeigniter. can anyone help me with this?

the sql query is

```
SELECT * FROM m_slow_log WHERE start_time BETWEEN CAST('2020-01-15%' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-01-22%' AS DATE);
```

Comment: please check this [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875668/codeigniter-getting-data-posted-in-between-two-dates ]

Comment: i've tried all answer on that thread. but none is working

Comment: can you show me your date formate which you save in DB?

Comment: What exactly is a problem ? The whole query needs to be converted for you or you have some error ? There are a lot of codeigniter questions with date's here...

Comment: its done. i read on [https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html] and here the result
```$query = "SELECT start_time, user_host, TIME_TO_SEC(query_time) AS query_time, sql_text, rekomendasi, status FROM m_slow_log WHERE start_time BETWEEN CAST(? AS DATE) AND CAST(? AS DATE)";
        $result = $ci->db->query($query, array($kondisi1, $kondisi2));```

Comment: Please read the documentation first then you are suppose to raise question. This type of questions are already answered, for more see here. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702792/how-to-translate-codeigniter-pre-formatted-query-into-an-original-mysql-query-e/57703372#57703372`

Answer (score 0):

Try use this one

```
public $table = 'm_slow_log';

function getbetween() {
$where = "start_time BETWEEN CAST('2020-01-15%' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-01-22%' AS DATE)";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

or you can set the date at controller/view

```
public $table = 'm_slow_log';

function getbetween($f, $t) {
$this->db->where("start_time BETWEEN '$f' AND '$t'");
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple query like

```
 $this->db->query(SELECT * FROM m_slow_log WHERE start_time BETWEEN CAST('2020-01-15%' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-01-22%' AS DATE))->row();
```